# Multi module project with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am creating a project with `spring-boot`.

Spring boot maven structure mandates that it has a parent defined to `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

I have a situation where I would like to package my application as a multi-module structure where I define modules which contain functionality related to a geography.

Something like this, each module has a jar packaging,

```
parent Pom
|
|-----------Core module
|
|-----------India Module
|
|----------Africa Module
|
|--------- Europe Module
```

Now, I can package my application depending on geography using maven profiles where in India profile only core module and India module are included and packaged.

How can I achieve it using spring boot where my parent is already defined to `spring-boot-starter-parent`?

Comment: You don't have to use the starter as a parent; that's just a convenience to pull in dependency management.

Comment: Agreed, please see my answer, on the ways possible. Please comment on the correcness

Comment: Agreed. Please see my answer. Please also comment on the correctness of my approach

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways one can do it,

1. use dependencyManagement in your parent pom as in

   ```
    <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
           <type>pom</type>
           <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
2. This is the way I am doing it. The root POM (with pom packaging) has spring boot as parent

   ```
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>
   ```

the module poms have root pom as parent.
The core module POM adds has dependency on other modules.
It also has 'spring-boot-maven-plugin' to create the fat jar.

The spring context is started with java -jar Core_xxx.release.jar

Off course if you have organization wise parent POM then first option would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can solve that problem using official Spring guidline and create Spring Boot Multi-Module project. Just follow the instruction https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about Spring Boot.

But in general using Spring this can be done by common configuration packages.
So in your main App/Configuration you do a:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.common.bootstrap")
```

And then you can just put module specific config in the bootstrap package for each module.
So just create a com.example.common.boostrap.AsiaModule and com.example.common.bootstrap.EuropeModule as Spring Configurations and you are good.

Comment: You should use @Import instead and define the ComponentScan on the modul configuration class.

Comment: I am putting @SpringBootApplication in my application start class whose package is x.y all packages in application are x.y.* so component scan is done if the class is in classpath. My question was different, where I was concerned about maven pom structure in multi-module spring boot application.